# MySQL Count and join tables

Tags: mysql, join, count

table_forum

```
|id_forum|name_forum|
|   1    |forum 1   |
|   2    |forum 2   |
```

table thread

```
|id_thread|name_thread|id_forum|
|   1     |thread 1   |   1    |
|   2     |thread 2   |   1    |
```

I need a query that returns

```
|name_forum|thread|
| forum 1  |  2   |
| forum 2  |  0   |
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Can you explain wat you wannt briefly..??

Comment: "|id_forum|name_forum| | 1 |forum 1 | | 2 |forum 2 |" wats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are two tables as i guess try like this

```
select table_forum.name_forum,count(table_thread.id_forum) from table_thread join table_forum where table_form.id_forum = table_thread.id_forum group by table_thread.id_forum
```